# Android BLE connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am new to Android Bluetooth API. I have to connect my app with a blood pressure monitor and get measurement data. I manage to get the connection working and get data when the device is not paired with my phone. However when it is paired, i get `status = 8` in my `onConnectionChanged`. Here is my code

This is my mGattCallback

```
 private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status, final int newState) {
        DebugLogger.debug("Status is "+status+" - new state is "+newState);

        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                mCallbacks.onDeviceConnected();
                // start discovering services
                gatt.discoverServices();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                mCallbacks.onDeviceDisconnected();
                gatt.close();
            }
        } else {
            mCallbacks.onError(ERROR_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE, status);
        }
    }
```

Here I connect or disconnect my device

```
 @Override
public void connect(final Context context, final BluetoothDevice device) {
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(context, true, mGattCallback);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void disconnect() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
    }
}
```

And this is for closing the whole connection after device is disconnected

```
 @Override
public void closeBluetoothGatt() {
    try {
        mContext.unregisterReceiver(mBondingBroadcastReceiver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // the receiver must have been not registered or unregistered before
    }

    if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBPMCharacteristic = null;
        mBatteryCharacteristic = null;
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }
}
```

I know that status 8 means there is a timeout in my connection. Am i missing something? Cause it is really strange why is it doing this only when i try to connect to a paired device

Comment: Yes you will get status 8 when it gets disconnected due to supervision time out. But what is your sequence of onConnectionStateChange? You should first have got a connected state change and some time after a disconnected state change (possibly with status 8). If you always get status 8 right after connected, it might be that your peripheral has the wrong bonding key.

Comment: When i press my connect button it shows me the device in the paired section of my pop up with devices. When i click on that device i first get status=0 and newStatus=2 and afterwards status=8 and newStatus=0. Is there a way to handle this time out?

Comment: Since you have set the autoConnect parameter to true, it should automatically reconnect when the peripheral advertises again and is in range. So you shouldn't need to do anything about it. I see you call gatt.close when disconnected, don't do that if you want it to auto reconnect. How long does it usually take before it disconnects with status 8 after it has connected?

Comment: it usually takes just a few seconds. Let me try what you said

Comment: Still nothing the same thing happens just when i try to connect to a alread paired device!

Comment: Maybe you have unstable BLE connection. Try another phone.

Comment: I did and i still have the same problem

Comment: So if you unpair from both sides, The connection does not drop? If so it seems there is some issues with the encryption. Try to enable the Bluetooth hci snoop log and see if there is some particular place where it always drops the connection.

Comment: the status 0x08 should not be GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION  ?